# Do Christians believe that Adam and Eve were Christians?

Tags: genesis, terminology, adam-and-eve, adam

I don't think I have ever heard either a Christian or a Jew or anyone else really refer to Adam and Eve by their race/religion.

It appears as if they are considered "pre-race" or "pre-religion".

If they consider Adam/Eve to have a race or religion, were they considered Jews?

Comment: this is a great question...after the cross we call his followers Christians (or at his ministry start would be fair conclusion), however, before the cross what were they? We cannot just say Jews...Adam and Eve were not Jews, nor was Noah! Far too many people i think use the term Jews when referring to pre incarnation followers of God in order to simply dispense with the law. However, the law predated Sinai by thousands of years, just as Adam and Eve predated Jews by thousands of years.

Comment: A catchall term for the faithful, from Adam to Abraham, Jews, faithful non Jews between Abraham and Christ, Messianic Jews after Christ and Christians could simply be "faithful" or "believers".

Comment: Christ hadn't descended to Earth yet, so I fail to see how they could be called Christian.

Comment: @MastnnChrist was there when he made it, presumably. That's both tongue in cheek and serious. C S Lewis's terrible and interesting "The Magician's Nephew" is a metaphor of the creation and has Aslan "singing" the universe into being.

Comment: Do Americans consider 12th century British people to be Americans?

Comment: What makes you think anyone would see Adam or Eve as Christians, Jews or come to that Muslims or anything else?

Of course it's vitally important what bveliefs the first people had but if you're going down that route, what clues d'you see?

Answer (score 8):

Abraham was the first Hebrew.

'Jews' come from Judah, the son of Jacob, Abraham's grandson.

Disciples were first called 'Christians' in Antioch during the first century.

God revealed himself to Adam by speaking to him, so Adam cannot be considered 'pre-religion'.

There was only one race in the beginning, because there was only one man in the beginning and since Eve was taken out of Adam she was the same 'race' as he.

They formed the human race, together, in the beginning.

These are the facts : they are all stated in your bible.

I do not know what various groups of self-identifying 'Christians' would say and it would be virtually impossible to find out without doing an enormous survey.

---

Adam received God's judgment against himself and Adam then responded to the promise of God (who promised a seed to the woman which would, from above, bruise the head of the serpent : which is a prophecy of the coming of Christ, who ascended on high and, from above, bruised the head of the Wicked One).

Adam responded and called his wife 'Eve' - which means the mother of all living. This evidences faith in Adam despite that he had transgressed.

Thereafter, when Cain 'goes out from the presence of the Lord' it is from Adam's household that he goes, showing that God was not a stranger to Adam's house. It was an household of faith.

So, although one cannot directly say that 'Adam was a Christian' he certainly showed faith in response to the promise of God concerning a coming Saviour.

Comment: You presumably meant that Judah was a son of Jacob, Abraham's grandson.

Comment: great answer Nijel. I think it would be fair to say that since Isaiah 9:6 calls the coming messiah "everlasting father", Christ existed eternally in the past...so my logical conclusion is that Adam was a Christian.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you. Corrected. My bad.

Comment: @Adam The terminology is applicable to all the patriarchs and saints of the Old testament _in theory_. But in practice 'Christian' can only properly refer to the revelation of the Son of God in incarnation, I would say. And it has only been extant, historically, since first used in Antioch.

Comment: Gen 3:31 - The Lord God made Garments of skin for Adam and his wife  and clothed them.  Doesn't this verse also figure in the discussion above ?

Comment: @dezkev I judged that to be another subject and for another question. One could include many things but one has to draw a line and simply answer what has been asked. Feel free to supply your own answer, that's what the website is for.

Answer (score 3):

"Christian" is a term that was invented by non-Christians, and later accepted by Christians::

> … So it was that for a whole year they assembled with the church and taught a great many people. And the disciples were first called Christians in Antioch.
> — [Acts 11:26](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/act/11/26/s_1029026)

The early Christians referred to themselves as "the Church of God":

> … has made you overseers, to shepherd the *church of God* which He purchased with His own blood.
> — [Acts 20:28](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/act/20/28/s_1038028)
>
> Give no offense, either to the Jews or to the Greeks or to the *church of God*,
> — [1 Corinthians 10:32](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/1co/10/32/s_1072032)
>
> For I am the least of the apostles, who am not worthy to be called an apostle, because I persecuted the *church of God*.
> — [1 Corinthians 15:9](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/1co/15/9/s_1077009)
>
> …

For the last 2000 years, Christians have considered themselves the bearers of the one true religion, a religion that includes additional revealed knowledge that expands on Judaism.

Before that, Jews considered themselves bearers of the one true religion, a religion that includes revealed knowledge in addition to what was known before Moses.

Before that, the ancestors of Judah (the first Jew) believed themselves bearers of the one true religion, a religion that includes revealed knowledge in addition to what Noah preserved on the ark.

Before that, some people believed themselves bearers of the one true religion, a religion that includes revealed knowledge in addition to what Adam and Eve knew.

Before that, Adam and Eve believed themselves bearers of the one true religion, based on revealed knowledge from God.

---

The Church of God is a continuous line, with each generation receiving additional knowledge about the one true religion.
They are all the same one true religion, with more knowledge being made available as time goes by.

The connection is even stronger for the many denominations that believe that the GOD (YHWH) of the Hebrew scriptures was actually the same being that was later incarnated as Jesus.

So it really doesn't matter what it is called, Adam and Eve were followers of the same religion that is today known as Christianity.

---

Similarly, Muslims, the LDS church, and others, would consider themselves the one true religion, and recipients of further revelation that is not accepted by the rest of Christianity.

Note that the question about race and Jews is irrelevant to religion.

Answer (score 0):

**Do Christians believe that Adam and Eve were Christians?**

The short answer is **no**.

Adam neither knew Jesus, nor his mission as the Christ. He certainly longed for it. What more God revealed to Adam, if anything, in those early days apart from Sacred Scripture has not come down to us. This is the bases of Adam’s faith.

As Abraham was the father of the Hebrew nation, and the father of many nations Adam was the father of the whole human race. As Abraham was the father of monotheism; Adam was the father the Adamic religion. Both are considered Patriarchs by most Christians.

Although Abraham saw Christ’s day and rejoiced in it; Adam hoped for it through his penance.

For having been banished from the Garden of Eden because of his sin, God remained merciful towards both Adam and Eve.

God gave them clothes to wear and a promise of a Savior.

How many times Adam must have pondered the words spoken to him from God in the hopes of a redeemer.

> And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your offspring and hers;
> he will crush your head, and you will strike his heel.” - [Genesis 3: 15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%203%3A15&version=NIV)

[Genesis 3:15: the promise of a Savior](https://wels.net/faq/genesis-315-the-promise-of-a-savior/)

Although Adam hoped to be redeemed, he nevertheless did not know Jesus as the Redeemer who is called the Christ; thus he could not have been a Christian. To say the opposite would imply that God somehow infused this knowledge to Adam, yet Scripture speaks nothing of this hypothetical information ever being revealed to Adam!

Answer (score -1):

Adam and Eve didn't have a religion because they only believed and trusted in God till they sinned.

The origin of the Jewish religion started when Moses was given the 10 commandments.In the Book of Numbers we are told about the Israelites of the new generation to follow Yahweh's instructions as given through Moses and are successful in all they attempt. That's when Judaism started really.

The origin of Chrisitanity only came during the time of Jesus. It spread quickly throughout the Roman Empire.

Comment: that might be true only if Christ did not exist before the incarnation.

Comment: There is no textual evidence to support your first sentence. The evidence is to the contrary.